# Are natural numbers a field with alternate addition and multiplication

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, field-theory

I've just started P.Halmos' book "Finite Vector Spaces", and at the first chapter, after defining the axioms of a field, there is an exercide that asks:
if we consider the non negative integers, can we redefine addition and multiplication so that they form a field?
Can't we, since $\mathbb{N}$ is countable just like $\mathbb{Q}$ that is a field, use some sort of coding to represent the field $\mathbb{Q}$ with it's operations with the natural numbers?

Comment: Yes, that would work. Any infinite set, or any finite set of prime power size $>1$, can be given the structure of a field.

Comment: I was always under the impression that they were.

Comment: Can someone give an example of how that would look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In general, if you have two sets that are in bijection with each other, and one of them has any sort of extra structure (e.g. is a group, a field, a vector space), then you can use the bijection to define the corresponding structure on the other set. This is sometimes referred to as "transport of structure."

Comment: can you be more specific on how you do that? give some examples?

Comment: Suppose you want to put a group structure on $\mathbb{N}$. Since $\mathbb{N}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{Z}$, there's some bijection $\phi$ between them. Then you can interpret $\mathbb{N}$ as a group where $a + b$ is interpreted as $\phi^{-1}(\phi(a) + \phi(b))$.

Comment: Here's a simple example. The set {0,1} has an addition operation: define "+" by 0+0=0, 0+1=1, 1+0=1, 1+1=0. The set {A,B} is in bijective correspondence with the set {0,1}. A corresponds to 0 and B corresponds to B. Then you can define "addition" on the set {A,B} as follows: A+A=A, A+B=B, B+A=B, B+B=A.

Comment: Here is an analogy that may make this helpful. Pretend that there is some country that uses an alphabet just like the English alphabet, except their letters are all sideways. Can they form words that correspond to ours? Yes. They would make their words the same but just using the sideways letters. This is because there is a bijection between the English alphabet and theirs.

Comment: This type of thing is ultimately just a relabeling of the elements of $\mathbb{Z}$. We're switching our labels in $\mathbb{N}$ to labels in $\mathbb{Z}$, performing the group operation in the more familiar setting, and then finally switching back to the initial labeling system that uses the elements of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: ok i get that $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$,  $\mathbb{Q}$ have all the same number of elements so for any isomorphism between them we can "hardcode" it into the "new" operation, and what we are left with is just a relabeling of elements. Therefore whatever attempt to make the naturals into a field by defining "new" operations, will result in making them isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. So the answer to the original question must be negative.

Comment: Your question was "if we consider the non negative integers, can we redefine addition and multiplication so that they form a field?" The answer to your question is yes as you just explained. The field constructed out of the nonnegative integers will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: You're right. So for countable sets there is only one way to construct a field? (up to isomorphism). And maybe someone can answer for uncountable sets?

Comment: That turns out to not be true but it is harder to explain. The field of rational numbers is countable, but you can create "field extensions" of $\mathbb{Q}$ that are also countable sets, but are not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ as fields.